# Maven fails to read resource of a sub-module when called by aggregator pom

Tags: maven

I have several modules that I run "`mvn clean install`" and have to maintain the order of them. To make my life easier and not having to change `TFS` or anything, I thought about creating [project aggregator](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation) that will have all my `sub-modules`, while they know nothing about this `aggregator`.
My project structure:

```
projectaggregator
|
+- submodule1
|
+- submodule2
```

**aggregator/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectaggregator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Project Aggregator</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../submodule1</module>
        <!--<module>../submodule2</module>-->       
    </modules>
</project>
```

And build fails with following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] submodule1
[INFO] Project Aggregator
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the MultiThreadedBuilder implementation with a thread count of 8
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project Aggregator 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building submodule1 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.3.1:generate (default) @ submodule1 ---
[INFO] reading from src/main/resources/yaml/decision.yaml
[INFO] reading from src/main/resources/yaml/decision.yaml
[ERROR] failed to read resource listing
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\yaml\decision.yaml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
...
[INFO] No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config! 

...
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] submodule1 ....................................... FAILURE [  3.983 s]
[INFO] Project Aggregator ............................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

**submodule1/pom.xml:**

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    ...
```

Clearly `submodule1` fails to find resources since we are running `submodule1` through `aggregator`.
Is there any way of resolving `relative path` to resources without having to modify `submodule1` pom file?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue when performing a multimodule build with swagger. Apparently a limitation with the swagger plugin when looking at paths of resources.
We can work around this by using maven variables `${project.basedir}` in our swagger plugin configuration  :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions><execution>
        <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yaml/decision.yaml</inputSpec>
        </configuration>
    </execution></executions>
</plugin>
```

Referenced from here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3583

Comment: Searched for a long time to find this!  Thank you @mailtobash.